# Pass python list to JavaScript in a jinja template

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I'm building a CRUD app using flask. I'm done with the create, read and delete. left with update part. The record to be updated will be shown in an html form to enable editing of the shown database record.

My problem is when the database record is shown in the form, i want a checkbox to be checked or a drop down list item to be selected depending on a value in the database record.

Is there a way to pass the result of a database query (1 record) to JavaScript as a JavaScript array, obtain the items in the JavaScript array, and use them in JavaScript statements to control check boxes?

```
@app.route('/update/<int:id>/')
def update(id):

    cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM profiles where entity_id = %s", (id,))
    row=list(cur.fetchall())
    cur.close()
    return render_template('profile-update.html', data = row)
```

below is the template

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue layout-top-nav">

  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions"             
     id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">company</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions"
     id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">partnership</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" 
     id="inlineRadio3" value="option3"`enter code here`>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i have research extensively on this but the suggested solutions do not seem to work

Comment: where is template? What did you try to do in template? Did you try to convert it to string with JavaScript's array in `update()` and send it as string which you can put in JavaScript code?

Comment: i've added the template

Comment: Why do you need a JS array to control checkboxes? I don't follow the question. If you passed a dictionary then you could decide whether a box should be checked or not at the time of rendering, not through an extra script

Comment: @roganjosh kindly demonstrate how this can be done

Answer (score -1):

You use the data passed into your template using [jinja markup](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/).

/templates/demo_template.html

```
*{{data}}*
```

/main.py

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/demo')
def demo():
    data = [dict(greeting='hello!'),dict(greeting='world!')]
    return flask.render_template('demo_template.html', data=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

[the output in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFWKw.png)

Comment: You might need to ass the `...|safe` filter to tell jinja that it should not escape special characters. Of course you should then make sure in the Python layer that the content actually *is* safe (i.e. sanitize any user-generated values first).

Comment: Upon re-reading the question, this answer does not addess the main point of the question: How to mark a checkbox item or drop-down item as "selected"